# How to select audio file when editText is clicked?

Tags: android, audio, android-edittext

When editText in fragment class (ReminderPage) is clicked, I want it  to open audio file so I can select music file as ringtone.

```
ringtone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {

                        Intent intent1 = new Intent();
                        intent1.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        intent1.setType("audio/*");
                        startActivityForResult(
                                Intent.createChooser(intent1, "Choose Sound File"), 6);
                    }
                });

  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data,Context context) {
        if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK && requestCode == 6) {
            Uri i = data.getData();  // getData
            String s = i.getPath(); // getPath
            File k = new File(s);  // set File from path
            if (s != null) {      // file.exists

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "ring");
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, k.length());
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, R.string.app_name);
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

                Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k
                        .getAbsolutePath());
                context.getContentResolver().delete(
                        uri,
                        MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\""
                                + k.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),values+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Uri newUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);

                try {
                    RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                            getActivity().ReminderPage, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,
                            newUri);
                } catch (Throwable t) {

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But I get errors and the onActivityResult is never used....

> Error:(473, 42) error: cannot find symbol variable ReminderPage
>   Error:(443, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method
>   from a supertype

After I change to getActivity().getContentResolver() and Reminder.this,  I get new errors

> Error:(444, 20) error: onActivityResult(int,int,Intent) in
>   ReminderPage cannot override onActivityResult(int,int,Intent) in
>   Fragment attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public
>   Error:(472, 36) error: method setActualDefaultRingtoneUri in class
>   RingtoneManager cannot be applied to given types; required:
>   Context,int,Uri found: ReminderPage,int,Uri reason: actual argument
>   ReminderPage cannot be converted to Context by method invocation
>   conversion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first error, try to replace `getActivity().ReminderPage` by `getActivity()` when calling `setActualDefaultRingtoneUri`.

Regarding the second error: there is no `Context context` parameter in the  [Fragment.onActivityResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)) method and the visibility should be `public`. You must respect the signature of the method when overriding it.

Replace

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data,Context context) {
```

by

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
```

And replace

```
context.getContentResolver()
```

by

```
getActivity().getContentResolver()
```

Comment: If I remove Context context, context cannot be resolved

Comment: onActivityResult must have an exact signature.  You can't add new parameters to it.  If you need to have another parameter, you need to store it in the instance level variables of the class.

Comment: @fiddler thanks. Do you know how to solve the others errors ?

Comment: @GabeSechan check my post again. Thanks

Comment: thanks... do you have idea on this ?`Error:(444, 20) error: onActivityResult(int,int,Intent) in ReminderPage cannot override onActivityResult(int,int,Intent) in Fragment
attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public`

Comment: @AI. The function in the parent class is public.  You can't make it more restrictive (protected or private), you must keep it as open or more open (in this case must keep it public).  I suggest you read up on Java inheritance, you seem to be a bit weak on it.

Comment: OK, it solved after change the protected to public.Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

this line could be the problem:

```
getActivity().ReminderPage
```

you could use

```
getActivity()
```

Comment: ok, I thought there was a class inside like this, than it's just ReminderPage.this if you are trying to pass the instance

Comment: I missed that you wrote the ReminderPage being a fragment